# Confusion in overloading the assignment operator =

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have not written the entire class definition here but here is what my assignment operator overloading looks like for the class -

```
    my_string& operator=(const my_string & obj) // copy assignment
    {
        __cleanup__(); // cleanup any existing data

        // Copy data from the newly assigned my_string object
        size = obj.size;
        buf = new char[size + 1]; // + 1 for the keeping the null character
        strncpy_s(buf, size + 1, obj.buf, size); // copy from the incoming buffer to character buffer of the new object
        return *this;
    }
```

I understand how this code works (return the object reference and stuff) and I understand that this code is correct but then I tried writing the code this way -

```
    void operator=(const my_string & obj) // copy assignment
    {
        __cleanup__(); // cleanup any existing data

        // Copy data from the newly assigned my_string object
        size = obj.size;
        buf = new char[size + 1]; // + 1 for the keeping the null character
        strncpy_s(buf, size + 1, obj.buf, size); // copy from the incoming buffer to character buffer of the new object
    }
```

and this works fine too! Now my question is why is the first implementation preferred over the second one? Why to even return something when you can assign the values to the calling object in the function itself? Thanks!

Comment: Returning a reference to the `*this` object being modified allows for chaining operations on the object

Comment: Try using the two in an expression like `a = b = c` where `a`, `b`, and `c` are all of type `my_string`.   You'll find one will work fine, and the other one has a diagnosable error.

Comment: Names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__cleanup__`) are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Comment: Pro tip: `a = a;` won’t work right.

Comment: @PeteBecker - That's true.  But that's a common feature of both versions of the function, not something associated with the differences (e.g. of return type) between them (which is what the question's about).

Comment: By clearing data before attempting the memory allocation, you do not provide a strong exception guarantee.

Comment: I think it's usually worth the overhead to employ the copy/swap idiom.

Comment: @Peter -- obviously. That's why it's **comment** and not an **answer**.